# Ayuda con mandar a llamar datos en react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

tengo un problema en que me pasaron unos datos y yo tengo que enseñarlos en una grafica, yo ocupo recharts aqui tengo el codigo que he relaizado

```
componentDidMount() {
this.vehiculoPorHoras()
}


vehiculoPorHoras = () => {
const _this = this
fetch("live/graph/hourly")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(datos => {
    console.log (datos)
    _this.setState({
      vehiculosH:datos.map((e,i)=>{
        let l=Object.keys(e)[0]
        let objl=e[l]
        return { name: l, horas: objl.count }
      })
    },()=>setTimeout(this.vehiculoPorHoras, 1000))
  })
```

}

abajo les pondre lo que me han mandado que se muestre
[[image: codigo[1]]

me llegan los primeros digitos que estan entre "" pero los que estan en verde no se muestran en la grafica, el codigo de la grafica ese si estoy seguro que lo tengo bien el problema es mandarlos a llamar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero, guardar `this` es inecesario ya que un arrow function no crea un nuevo contexto, así que te puedes evitar eso.
Supongo que el valor de tu objeto son las horas. Entonces cuando haces esto:
`return { name: l, horas: objl.count }`
La propiedad count no existe en tu objeto.

```
this.setState({
      vehiculosH:datos.map((e,i)=>{
        let name;
        let horas;
        for (let property in e) {
           if (object.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
              name = property;
              horas = e[property]
           }
         }
        return { name, horas}
      })
```

La verdad no lo he probado, pero te puedes basar en eso.
`hasOwnProperty` se utiliza ya que cuando se itera el objeto muestra algunas propiedades del objeto que no se necesitan.